# JasperViewer does not print unicode characters in Windows

Tags: jasper-reports

Not sure why JasperViewer does not print unicode characters in Windows. I tried to install some Bengali Fonts but did not work.

I am simply retrieving data from mysql and in the report i am replacing the numbers to Bengali unicode numbers. It works fine in Linux (debian). But when i run the Application jar file in Windows (10), The font is completely broken. Nothing displayed except the Table.

What am i doing wrong?

It is harder today to format the xml code here! So i pasted it on http://pastebin.com/XC3EiZyF

Font Extension:
[image]

[image]

Java Method:

```
public void ClickButton(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, JRException, SQLException {


    //System.out.println(dir);
    String date = viewReport.getText();



    String reportSrcFile = "/home/famed/IdeaProjects/Salary Sheet/src/SalarySheet/salary2.jrxml";



    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/rtemp/salary2.jrxml");
    System.out.println(report.toString());

    Connection conn = SqlConnect.con();


    // Parameters for report
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("repDate", viewReport.getText());
    if(displayDate.getText().isEmpty()){
        parameters.put("displayDate",viewReport.getText());
    }
    else {
        parameters.put("displayDate",displayDate.getText());
    }

    System.out.println("The Date:");
    System.out.println(parameters.get("repDate"));

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,
            parameters, conn);


    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(print);
    jv.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jv.setTitle("Test Report");

    jv.setVisible(true);
}
```

JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<detail>
    <band height="304" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="168" y="104" width="200" height="200" uuid="433fbb6e-081e-4bab-ab86-a02e4a7187c9">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 1_TH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 1_CH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 1_TD"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset2" uuid="fd0beb84-562e-4cb7-bd56-6ff5ee927304">
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="100" uuid="112d200e-48b9-473a-83c8-0d4cdc7ac60c">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table 1_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="8ab8f29f-6229-4abb-9754-489041715c02"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[নাম]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="Table 1_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="03c38867-008d-495f-9429-c980edcec9fa"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf($F{emp_name}).replaceAll("0","০").replaceAll("1","১").replaceAll("2","২").replaceAll("3","৩").replaceAll("4","৪").replaceAll("5","৫").replaceAll("6","৬").replaceAll("7","৭").replaceAll("8","৮").replaceAll("9","৯")]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="100" uuid="08c7b00b-bb51-4974-9f80-437a800016c0">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table 1_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="92539beb-73ef-4729-be59-e744fa0339fb"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[বাড়ী ভাড়া]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="Table 1_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="07286a2f-7346-40ee-aa69-4c68851020a4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf($F{home_fare_percent}).replaceAll("0","০").replaceAll("1","১").replaceAll("2","২").replaceAll("3","৩").replaceAll("4","৪").replaceAll("5","৫").replaceAll("6","৬").replaceAll("7","৭").replaceAll("8","৮").replaceAll("9","৯")]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: `What am i doing wrong?` - You should show your code (Java + jrxml). Are you using the [*Font Extensions*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: Yes, I am adding font extension. The JRXML file : http://pastebin.com/XC3EiZyF

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I made it working. I was forgotten to change the font name after adding the jar files!